# Correlation relationship basic question

Tags: statistics, correlation

I am not an expert in statistics, but I was reading a paper that measures correlation relationships and I just stopped by the study design in that paper as it doesn't make sense to me. The problem is that it studies the correlation between x and y, where in fact x is calculated from y such that: x=y+z

My understanding is that when we study correlation relationship, we look into 2 independent variables. So with x=y+z,  we already know that they are correlated.

Am I missing anything? any thoughts?

Comment: If two variables are independent, their correlation is 0, so you typically are interested in how correlated two variables are if you think there's a relationship between them.

Comment: Maybe I was not precise when I said "independent". What I mean is that two variables that we have no prior knowledge (such as a formula) of such correlation or relation

Comment: It's pretty typical to start from some hypothesized relationship between variables and test that hypothesis. Are $X$ and $Y$ both measured values in the paper you're reading? If so, then it just sounds like the researchers want to confirm whether the relationship they expect between the variables exists in the data. If they're actually calculating $X$ using data on $Y$ and then measuring the correlation, that wouldn't make sense (the correlation would just be $1$).

Comment: Both x and y are taken from a dataset, and x measure in the dataset includes y, anyway. Thank you so much for the clarification